# How to check if any variable in one array is in another

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop

I'm developing a program with MatLab that calculates powers of numbers, adds them together, and then sees if any of the first set of numbers (numbers to powers) equals any of the added numbers to powers. I'm trying to check this for each value in the first array, however, I am getting an output like this:

```
m =
       1
     128
    2187
   16384
   78125
  279936
  823543
 2097152
 4782969
10000000
```

for each `m` value, which is just the result of a simple `for` loop of the array. So when I go to check if `m` is in the array, it checks is `[1, 128,2187,16384,78125...]` in the array, and the answer is no. How can I get it to evaluate each individual entry, like this:

```
Array n is [1,128,2187,16384]
for m = n
m = 1
Is m in array? No
m = 128
Is m in array? No
m = 2187
Is m in array? Yes
m = 16384
Is m in array? No
end
```

My code is below:

```
C = [];
D = [];
E = [];
F = [];
numbers1 = [];
numbers2 = [];

numbers = 10;
powers = 10;

for i = 1:numbers 
    for j = 3:powers  
        C = [C;i^j]; 
    end  
    C = transpose(C);
    D = [D;C];  
    C = [];
end

[~,b] = unique(D(:,1)); % indices to unique values in first column of D
D(b,:);                  % values at these rows

for i = D
    for a = D
        E = [E;i+a];
    end
    E = transpose(E);
    F = [F;E];  
    E = [];
end

[~,b] = unique(F(:,1)); % indices to unique values in first column of F
F(b,:);                  % values at these rows

for m = D % this is the for loop mentioned above
        m
end
```

Comment: Could you explain your problem more clearly? And your code is not directly runnable: `??? Undefined function or variable 'number'.`

Comment: @LuisMendo I tried to explain it better, and I made the code runnable (forgot to take out that line).

Comment: Instead using a for loop, the function `find` can be a better idea no?

Comment: @AlexandreBizeau It looks like `find` just returns the index of non-zero elements, correct? How would that replcae a `for` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example vectors:

```
>> m = [1 3 5 9];
n = [5 2 1 4 8];
```

1. To check if each element of vector `m` is in `n`, use [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html):

   ```
   >>ismember(m,n)
   ans =
        1     0     1     0
   ```
2. To get the values, not the indices: use logical indexing on `m`:

   ```
   >> m(ismember(m,n))
   ans =
        1     5
   ```

   or directly use [`intersect`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html):

   ```
   >> intersect(m,n)
   ans = 
        1     5
   ```

Comment: That's perfect! Is there any way I can check if any of the answer is 1 (true) and then determine what number that is?

Comment: @hichris123 Try `find(ismember(m,n))`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, but then how do I find what number was in both vectors?

Comment: @hichris123 Use `m(ismember(m,n))`

Comment: So it looks like if there is no repeated number, it outputs 1?

Comment: @hichris123 Or, more directly, `intersect(m,n)`

Comment: @hichris123 If there is no common number it gives an empty matrix